# Does angular js have drag event or drag directive?

Tags: angularjs

using angular binding is really helpful instead of jQuery to manipulate DOM, but I don't know how to deal with drag event without jQuery,

For example, I want drag the second box up to first, or drag ng-repeat li to change the order

does angular have drag event or directive ?

```
<div>
<li>This is first box</li>
<li>This is second box</li>
</div>

//or like below 
<div><li ng-repeat="box in boxs | orderBy:'order'">{{box.name}}{{box.order}}</li></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried this? http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/

Comment: Or this http://codef0rmer.github.io/angular-dragdrop/#/

Comment: do you need any more help with this question?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable

Include the sortable.js file in your document.
(Note the additional dependencies on jquery and jqueryUI)

Add the sortable module as a dependency to your application module

```
var myAppModule = angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.sortable'])
```

Then alter your markup like this:

```
<ul ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="boxs">
    <li ng-repeat="box in boxs | orderBy:'order'">
        {{box.name}}{{box.order}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Finally add some configuration for your "sortable" in your controller.

```
$scope.sortableOptions = {
    update: function(e, ui) { 
        // do something when the sortorder has changed
        // e.g. save the new order to your backend...
    }
};
```